# Neo4j favorite queries list

Tags: neo4j

I create several neo4j databases for several demo projects on my laptop.
When I open any of my projects I can see ALL the queries I created for ALL projects.
How can I split that any query will be viewed only from the DB it belongs too?

Thanks Tal

Comment: Sounds like you actually have only a **single** neo4j DB. Right?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single DB, then keeping your "logical subgraphs" apart when doing queries requires crafting your data model so that each subgraph can be queried independently of the others.

A typical approach would be to use specific node labels for each subgraph, and to not share those labels between subgraphs. If you do that, then your queries can specify that you only care about the nodes with those labels.

A more exact answer would depend on your actual use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.I figure it up.
For each database, I should configure a separate PORT.
Since all my databases refer to One port 7474 the queries from all the databases were mixed together.
Tal